# Gradle build, UP-TO-DATE check only

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to do an up-to-date check of the tasks only, without executing the tasks that are not up-to-date? The motivation behind this is debugging a script with a lot of lengthy tasks and a complicated task tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking gradle documentation and code there is no such option. Thinking about it this makes a lot of sense as gradle up-to-date logic is being executed **during the execution phase** as its result may be dependent on the actual outputs of the previous tasks. In other words, in order to know whether a task is up-to-date all its task dependencies has to be either executed or resolved as `UP-TO-DATE`, thus your ask is not possible.